# Git untracked files and subfolders

Tags: git

I have git repo that is not showing untracked files:

```
[status]
showUntrackedFiles = no
```

now, I have added files from several subfolders to the git (i know git does not have a concept of subfolders).

Would it be possible to somehow see untracked files from subfolders?

I was thinking this:

- list all tracked files, extract all direct subfolders
- for each subfolder show untracked files
- stage collected untracked files to git

I am not sure if I can get the step #2 somehow?

---

I other words, I need to hide untracked files only on 'deeplevel' 1, i.e. only for the root.

Comment: Is ignoring files in the root dir (but not in subdirectories) with `.gitignore` or `.git/info/exclude` an option? That won't just affect `git status`, but many (all?) git commands that act on untracked files.

Comment: Unfortunately not - I have no control over what will be added to the root, so can't really of updating the .gitignore :(

Comment: Well, `.git/info/exclude` is under your control and purely local (won't affect other clones of the repository.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made things differently: https://github.com/igr/homer/blob/master/homer#L65

- First I find tracked folders.
- Then iterate all untracked files
- if file belongs to tracked folder, it's a match.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.git/info/exclude` as das-g suggested, with a pattern like this:

```
# Ignore everything...
*
# ...except subdirectories...
!*/
# ...and their contents.
!*/*
```

You need both exceptions because:

> [It is not possible to re-include a file if a parent directory of that file is excluded.](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore#_pattern_format)